# How to get hosting website url in silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight App is hosting on a web site. How to get the hosting url in silverlight app code?
For example if the hosting site is `http://mysite/startingpage.aspx`, then how to get "http://mysite" in SL app code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will give you the location of the page hosting the `.xap` file:

```
var pageUri = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.ToString();
```

This will give you the location of your `.xap` file:

```
var applicationUri = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri;
```

You can then take either of these strings and parse out the parts you don't need.